# Private Repository in Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I want to setup a private Repository in Jfrog Artifactory which will have all the jar files, property files, xml files etc required for project. I will host it in internal server for my project team

Has anyone done like this?

There is one Maven tag which will be used to pull all the jars from private  rep. to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

JFrog runs on a tomcat server against a built in Derby database.  Download and install, then you can create your repository.

From within JFrog it will create the maven seettings.xml file for you to point your repository.

It's an ideal tool for local dev teams.

For install see https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Windows

You can create a virtual repository which can include you own physical "private" repository and maven central.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Jfrog Artifactory, you can create a "private" local repository:

1.)Go to the admin panel / Repositories / Local / New and configure the name(Ex: maven-private-local) and the type (for your using Maven or generic).

2.)Go to the admin panel / Security / Permisions / New and select your repository (Ex: maven-private-local) and add users that you want to can Manage/Delete/Overwrite/Deploy/Cache/Annotate or read the "private repository".

Also how comment Essex Boy, you can create a virtual repository that include your "private repository" and maven central.